# Run-Time error '438': Object Doesn't support this property or method vba

Tags: vba, collections, runtime

I have had a a hard time dealing with error 438. I am trying to save the property of salary to each and every employee in the collection.

```
   Public Sub Click()
    Dim employee As Collection
    Set employee = New Collection
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim E1 As Variant
    Dim j As Integer
    n = 528
    Dim t As String

    For i = 3 To n
       t = "T" + CStr(i)
       Set E1 = New clsEmployee
       E1.salary = Sheets("A").Range(t).Value
    Next i

   End sub
```

Comment: There's no code here to add anything to the `employee` collection

Comment: Does `clsEmployee` *have* a `salary` property?  Is it public?

Comment: @barrowc I am giving the value of salary to patient from excel with this line : E1.salary = Sheets("A").Range(t).Value.

Comment: `E1` is a `clsEmployee`.  Is patient a different class?  Can you post the code for the `clsEmployee.salary` property Get and Let?

Comment: @Comintern your first comment solved the problem. I have made salary public and there is no error anymore. You can write it as answer if you would like.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I'll convert to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can conceivably see getting that specific runtime error with the posted code is if `clsEmployee` does not have a public `.salary` property. This can be confirmed by changing the declaration from...

```
Dim E1 As Variant
```

...to:

```
Dim E1 As clsEmployee
```

In this case it will give a compile error "Method or data member not found" instead of a runtime error.

The solution is to add the property if it doesn't exist or make it public if it does.